# What is the CLR doing "automagically" when a type is annotated [serializable]?

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, attributes, serializable

I understand that when you annotate a type with `[serializable]` it tells the CLR that this type can be serialized.

I don't like this seeming like "black box" magic to me. I want to know what it does when I mark it with this attribute.

In addition it would be helpful to know what it then does when I actually try to serialize an object.

P.S. if the answer to this question can pertain to the handling of *any* attribute, please feel free to edit my question title and question to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: As a fully supported feature of .Net, attributes are metadata attached to a class and as such are discoverable via reflection. They're an (arguably) great alternative to marker interfaces. They're usually just simple classes that may or may not hold data. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720537(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: What doesn't make sense to me here is that you have to mark a class as [serializable] to make it so. What is the CLR doing that it can't just attempt a serialization when you attempt to serialize an object? Why does it need to know beforehand that you are going to try to serialize an instance of the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Common Language Runtime (CLR) manages how objects are laid out in memory and the .NET Framework provides an automated serialization mechanism by using reflection. When an object is serialized, the name of the class, the assembly, and all the data members of the class instance are written to storage. Objects often store references to other instances in member variables. When the class is serialized, the serialization engine keeps track of all referenced objects already serialized to ensure that the same object is not serialized more than once. The serialization architecture provided with the .NET Framework correctly handles object graphs and circular references automatically. The only requirement placed on object graphs is that all objects referenced by the object that is being serialized must also be marked as Serializable. If this is not done, an exception will be thrown when the serializer attempts to serialize the unmarked object.

this part of this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx

Comment: So until you actually attempt to serialize an object, the only thing that is happening is that you get the _serializable_ metadata? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that happens is that `typeof(MyClass).IsSerializable` will be true. Then there is a statement saying `if (!typeToBeSerialized.IsSerializable) throw ...` in the code that does the actual serialization.